# Access Primary and Foreign Key Linking Problem

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys

I hope someone can help with this. I have an Access database with PONumber as a Primary key in one table, and as a foreign key in a second table. The tables are set as source to a form and subform, with PONumber as master and child keys linking them.

The database is split, and it's only since I split the database I've been having this problem.

As you can see, when I open the table directly in the back end, it shows as expected:

[Back End Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNDU8.jpg)

But when I open it from the front end, the linked table doesn't appear.

[Front End Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ennnD.jpg)

Data entered in the subform appears as expected in both tables on the linked key.

I have deleted and recreated the table relationships with referential integrity enforced, and I have deleted the tables from the fornt end and re-linked them. I have compacted and repaired the database. I feel like this is an Access bug, but maybe there's something I haven't set up right?

Possibly related: when I delete all rows from the tables and compact the database, the autonumber does not reset to 1, but continues from the last entry (in the screenshots attached, I deleted 45 previous rows, but autonumber picked up again from 46).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- Open the linked table in design view
- In the Properties pane, select for Subdatasheet name the subtable to
  use (tbpPODetails)
- Save the linked table

Comment: Well, it says don't use comments to say thanks, but I can't see another way to say thanks :-)

Comment: Well, yes - you can both upvote the answer and mark it as such, if you like.